# rstudent() returns incorrect result for an "mlm" (linear models fitted with multiple LHS)

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, lm, mlm

I know that the support for linear models with multiple LHS is limited. But when it is possible to run a function on an "mlm" object, I would expect the results to be trusty. When using `rstudent`, strange results are produced. Is this a bug or is there some other explanation?

In the example below `fittedA` and `fittedB` are identical, but in the case of `rstudent` the 2nd column differs.

```
y <- matrix(rnorm(20), 10, 2)
x <- 1:10
fittedA <- fitted(lm(y ~ x))
fittedB <- cbind(fitted(lm(y[, 1] ~ x)), fitted(lm(y[, 2] ~ x)))
rstudentA <- rstudent(lm(y ~ x))
rstudentB <- cbind(rstudent(lm(y[, 1] ~ x)), rstudent(lm(y[, 2] ~ x)))
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Setup

```
set.seed(0)
y <- matrix(rnorm(20), 10, 2)
x <- 1:10
fit <- lm(y ~ x)           ## class: "mlm", "lm"
fit1 <- lm(y[, 1] ~ x)     ## class: "lm"
fit2 <- lm(y[, 2] ~ x)     ## class: "lm"

rstudent(fit)
#          [,1]        [,2]
#1   0.74417620  0.89121744
#2  -0.67506054 -0.50275275
#3   0.76297805 -0.74363941
#4   0.71164461  0.01075898
#5   0.03337192  0.03355209
#6  -1.75099724 -0.02701558
#7  -1.05594284  0.56993056
#8  -0.48486883 -0.35286612
#9  -0.23468552  0.79610101
#10  2.90701182 -0.93665406

cbind(rstudent(fit1), rstudent(fit2))
#          [,1]        [,2]
#1   0.74417620  1.90280959
#2  -0.67506054 -0.92973971
#3   0.76297805 -1.47237918
#4   0.71164461  0.01870820
#5   0.03337192  0.06042497
#6  -1.75099724 -0.04056992
#7  -1.05594284  1.02171222
#8  -0.48486883 -0.64316472
#9  -0.23468552  1.69605079
#10  2.90701182 -1.25676088
```

As you've observed, only the result for the first response is correctly returned by `rstandard(fit)`.

---

#### Why `rstudent` fails on "mlm"

The thing is, there is no "mlm" method for `rstudent`.

```
methods(rstudent)
#[1] rstudent.glm* rstudent.lm*
```

When you call `rstudent(fit)`, the S3 method dispatching mechanism finds `rstudent.lm` instead, because `inherits(fit, "lm")` is `TRUE`. Unfortunately, `stats:::rstudent.lm` is not doing the correct computation for an "mlm" model.

```
stats:::rstudent.lm
#function (model, infl = lm.influence(model, do.coef = FALSE), 
#    res = infl$wt.res, ...) 
#{
#    res <- res/(infl$sigma * sqrt(1 - infl$hat))
#    res[is.infinite(res)] <- NaN
#    res
#}
```

`lm.influence` does not give the correct `sigma` for "mlm". The underlying C routine `C_influence` only computes `sigma` for an "lm". If you give `lm.influence` an "mlm", only the result for the first response variable is returned.

```
## pass in "mlm"
.Call(stats:::C_influence, fit$qr, FALSE, residuals(fit), 10 * .Machine$double.eps)$sigma
# [1] 1.3130265 1.3216357 1.3105706 1.3171621 1.3638689 1.1374385 1.2668101
# [8] 1.3416338 1.3586428 0.9180828

## pass in "lm"
.Call(stats:::C_influence, fit1$qr, FALSE, residuals(fit1), 10 * .Machine$double.eps)$sigma
# [1] 1.3130265 1.3216357 1.3105706 1.3171621 1.3638689 1.1374385 1.2668101
# [8] 1.3416338 1.3586428 0.9180828
```

Obviously for an "mlm" the `sigma` should be a matrix. Now given this incorrect `sigma`, ["recycling rule"](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-intro.html#The-recycling-rule) is applied behind the `"/"` in the following line of `stats:::rstudent.lm`, because the `res` (residuals) on its left is a matrix but the stuff on its right is a vector.

```
res <- res / (infl$sigma * sqrt(1 - infl$hat))
```

Effectively, computational result is only correct for the first response variable; all the rest of response variables would use the wrong `sigma`.

---

#### R core team needs to patch a number of diagnostic functions

Note that almost all functions listed in doc page `?influence.measures` are buggy for "mlm". They should have issued an warning saying that "mlm" methods are not implemented yet.

`lm.influnce` needs be patched at C-level. As soon as this is done, `rstudent.lm` would work correctly on "mlm".

Ohter functions can be easily patched at R-level, for example, `stats:::cooks.distance.lm` and `stats:::rstandard`. At the moment (R 3.5.1) they are:

```
stats:::cooks.distance.lm
#function (model, infl = lm.influence(model, do.coef = FALSE), 
#    res = weighted.residuals(model),
#    sd = sqrt(deviance(model)/df.residual(model)), 
#    hat = infl$hat, ...) 
#{
#    p <- model$rank
#    res <- ((res/(sd * (1 - hat)))^2 * hat)/p
#    res[is.infinite(res)] <- NaN
#    res
#}

stats:::rstandard.lm
#function (model, infl = lm.influence(model, do.coef = FALSE), 
#    sd = sqrt(deviance(model)/df.residual(model)), type = c("sd.1", 
#        "predictive"), ...) 
#{
#    type <- match.arg(type)
#    res <- infl$wt.res/switch(type, sd.1 = sd * sqrt(1 - infl$hat), 
#        predictive = 1 - infl$hat)
#    res[is.infinite(res)] <- NaN
#    res
#}
```

and they can be patched (by using `outer`) with

```
patched_cooks.distance.lm <-
function (model, infl = lm.influence(model, do.coef = FALSE), 
    res = weighted.residuals(model),
    sd = sqrt(deviance(model)/df.residual(model)), 
    hat = infl$hat, ...) 
{
    p <- model$rank
    res <- ((res / c(outer(1 - hat, sd))) ^ 2 * hat) / p
    res[is.infinite(res)] <- NaN
    res
}

patched_rstandard.lm <- 
function (model, infl = lm.influence(model, do.coef = FALSE), 
    sd = sqrt(deviance(model)/df.residual(model)), type = c("sd.1", 
        "predictive"), ...) 
{
    type <- match.arg(type)
    res <- infl$wt.res/switch(type, sd.1 = c(outer(sqrt(1 - infl$hat), sd)), 
        predictive = 1 - infl$hat)
    res[is.infinite(res)] <- NaN
    res
}
```

A quick test:

```
oo <- cbind(cooks.distance(fit1), cooks.distance(fit2))  ## correct result
all.equal(cooks.distance(fit), oo)
#[1] "Mean relative difference: 0.8211302"
all.equal(patched_cooks.distance.lm(fit), oo)
#[1] TRUE

rr <- cbind(rstandard(fit1), rstandard(fit2))  ## correct result
all.equal(rstandard(fit), rr)
#[1] "Mean relative difference: 0.5290036"
all.equal(patched_rstandard.lm(fit), rr)
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 3):

Thank you @李哲源; see also https://www.r-project.org/bugs.html on how to report bugs ... where they are noticed better by the R core team. Also, there, we could give better credit for patches..
Als note that R's source code - notably it's development version - is always available via svn ("subversion") or also a webbrowser at https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/

Both, `cooks.distance.lm()`'s and `rstandard.lm()`'s source code is in https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/library/stats/R/lm.influence.R ....  all for a next time.   Your proposed small code changes via `outer()` are good enough of course.

Thank you very much for the thorough analysis and your well proposed bug fix!

Comment: The simple bug fix for `cooks.distance()` and `rstandard()` has been comitted to the R (development) sources now, and I plan to also port them to "R 3.5.1 patched" so the fix will appear in any next R release.     As you @李哲源 correctly note, to fix `rstudent()` -- and also other uses of `lm.influence()` it is necessary to improve the compiled code, not just the C but also underlying Fortran. I have started doing that.. but that will take a bit more time.

Comment: Much much more changes were needed to fix the problem for `rstudent()` and related functions, built on `lm.influence()` as @李哲源 did mention.  I have pretty systematically addressed this and committed the changes (including C and Fortran) with svn rev 75334 (visible in github mirror as  https://github.com/wch/r-source/commit/815b3b72a4a839d7aa6036ce49e48be8d3b50b77).